# Why is my response coming in multiple messages? How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Function in which I am trying to hit a 3rd party API.  If my response is short, it comes back all at once, and everything works.  However, when my response is too long, it comes back in two parts.  This causes my JSON parsing to fail.

```
import * as https from 'https';

export function search(searchTerm: string): Promise<IResponse> {
    return new Promise<IResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
        const options =
        {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: port,
            path: 'search?query=' + searchTerm,
            method: 'GET',
            headers:
            {
                'x-app-id': appID,
                'x-app-key': appKey
            }
        };
        const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
            response.on('data', (data) => {
                const json = data.toString('utf8');

                //1. This prints out
                //3. This prints out again (after the JSON parsing fails)
                console.log(json);

                //2. This fails "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
                resolve(convertToResponse(json));
            });
        });
        request.end();
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of using the "request" module, use "request-promise" to get the entire response in one buffer.  Also, it will simplify your code greatly.  Or, one of these more modern libraries: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you, but I am not using the request module.

Comment: In any event, you will save a lot of effort if you use a more modern alternative that gives you a promise to work with instead of the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Bigger Responses get send as chunks. So you need to collect the chunks and join them after you recived all of them. The 'data' event gets dispatched  when you recive a chunk and the 'end' event gets dispatched when you recived all chunks.

An short example from the [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

```js
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
```